# Bootstrap CSS media Min device width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my own project.My menu have 6 buttons.
I did it with Bootstrap but when i open in Iphone web browser, the menu comes one row - one button.
I want to show two buttons for a row.
 Maybe i can't explain my problem, so i added a screenshot.

here is the image;
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGZIJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGZIJ.png)

Thanks for everything,
here is my code below;

```
 <div class="box first">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="center">
                        <a href="orders.php"><img src="img/logo/siparis.png"              width="78px" height="78px">
                            <h4 style="text-align:center">Sipariş takibi</h4></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/.col-md-4-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com/example-sifre-yenileme.html">
                        <div class="center">
                            <img src="img/logo/email_unut.png" width="78px" height="78px">
                            <h4 style="text-align:center">Şifre değiştirme</h4></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/.col-md-4-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="center">
                        <a href="orderhasar.php"> <img src="img/logo/hasar.png" width="78px" height="78px">
                            <h4 style="text-align:center">Hasarlı sipariş destek talebi</h4></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/.col-md-4-->
            </div>
            <!--/.row-->
        </div>
```

Comment: So what you want is to have them all in one line?

Comment: in one `row` you can only put `12 columns` not `18 columns`

Comment: @Leonidas No, i want to show in one row-two buttons.

Comment: add your code here "code snippet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want all the menu items to show side by side horizontally?
If so, you need to add a XS class declaration for mobile:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-2">
```

With col-xs-2, it will fit 6 items in a row (12 total columns, 2 columns per menu item, 6 menu items).

You might have to play with the size of the items then!

**EDIT:**

To show a 2 button row, add **col-xs-6** instead.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
```

Comment: İ have 6 buttons. Should we use 3 row,2 colums? When i try to '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">' , the first two rows comes ok.

Comment: Well, it depends on the size of the buttons and how you want it to look.
The options are: col-xs-2, col-xs-4 and col-xs-6. This will create: one row, 6 icons, 2 rows, 3 icons, or 3 rows, 2 icons. Give it a try and see what fits you best.

Comment: I tried this code and it's done.'<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">'. Thanks for everything

Comment: Cool! Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct! Thanks!

Comment: When i try on [link](http://cybercrab.com/screencheck) everything is ok but when i try on my own Samsung S3, it's not working fine

Comment: Can u describe what happens on S3?

Comment: I tried on [link](http://cybercrab.com/screencheck) with 320*480. It shows so fine as i want. But i have find a another problem.Not about your solution. Your solution is great. Thanks. I marked as answer.Thanks you so much